# Library managing lifetime of objects, use smart pointers or raw?

Tags: c++, oop, c++14

Rolling my own GUI library for a side-project.  Refactoring to use smart pointers; however, I ran into an issue.

I'm aware that you do not want to to use smart pointers across DLL boundaries for obvious reasons.  But I feel dirty using 'new' in application code.  See below:

```
// MYFINANCEAPP.H
class MyFinanceApp : public Application
{

MyFinanceApp() : mMainWindow(make_unique<Window>())
{
  mMainWindow->AddControl(*(new Button("testButton")));
}

private:
  std::unique_ptr<Window> mMainWindow;
};

// WINDOW.H
class Window
{
public:
  void AddControl(Control& control)  //QUESTION: HOW DO I GET SMART POINTER HERE???
  {
    mControls.emplace_back(&control)
  }
private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Control>> mControls;  //Want to use smart pointers so I am not responsible for managing...
};
```

Am I better to use C++98 style and semantics and handle it myself.  Obviously I do not want to pass smart pointers across the interface boundary (i.e. AddControl), but I don't want to be responsible for handling the lifetime of the controls.

Additionally, I feel really dirty using `new Button("testButton")`.

Comment: What are these "obvious reasons"? Separate heaps affect dynamically-allocated objects regardless of whether they are owned by smart or raw pointers...

Comment: @Quentin I think he is talking about ABI issue. With dynamic library, it's easier to have a C interface since C ABI is well defined while C++ ABI is not.

Comment: @nefas is correct.

Comment: @nefas but that'd mean that absolutely no member function could be called either. -- Edit: alright, you probably should add to the question that your goal is to make a C wrapper around your API.

Comment: @Quentin yes, I re-read the question and it's not very clear. You can't do thing halfway: or you expose a C interface (no smart pointer, no classes, ...) (safer) or you can expose a C++ interface (then you can use smart pointer) (will require compilation for specific compiler, compiler version ...)

Comment: I see what you're getting at now.  However, even though ABI might not be an issue.  Wouldn't I be forcing my users to use smart pointers?  Is it possible for them to not even know smart pointers are being used in the underlying implementation (unless they looked at the .h or I used PIMPL)?

Comment: `Window::AddControl` doesn't take a pointer as an argument, smart or otherwise, but `MyFinanceApp::MyFinanceApp()` tries to pass a pointer to that function. Which is the correct interface for that function?

Comment: The new code is not going to compile either: `std::unique_ptr<Control>` requires a non-`const` `Control` pointer to construct, and you can only get `Control const*` from taking the address of a `Control const&`.

Comment: @Xirema, fixed.

Comment: @keelerjr12 if you don't want your user to use smart pointer, don't return pointer or take pointer as function parameter. If you do return or take pointer, use smart pointer, it'll be better for everyone ."_even though ABI might not be an issue_" I'm not sure I understand what you mean: do you mean that having a C++ interface (thus an unstable ABI) is not a problem for you ?

Comment: If I correctly understood your problem: 1. Your client interface must be as generic as possible. 2. "I feel dirty using 'new' in application code" Would `create/add_ref/release` feel better? 3. stl in client interface: what if your client is using a different stl implementation?

Comment: I need a pointer because I need the polymorphic behavior of Control, Button, etc.  Therefore, I must use a vector of pointers to Controls. Then I can override specific behaviors.

Comment: I don't understand what's the issue with the the smart pointers. If you care about the ABI issue, use a C interface, if not, you can use smart pointers.

Comment: What, exactly, ABI instabilities are you worried about?  Symbol mangling changing?  std version changing?  Calling convention changing?  What in your above code  do you imagine living "in the DLL" and what "in the application"?

Comment: My impression was that there were a number of issues with C++, and especially smart pointers, across DLLs to include memory management, deletion, name-mangling, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reminder that ABI issues can be circumvented if you simply make a guarantee that you won't release a DLL compiled on a different compiler/version/platform than the primary executable.

At any rate, regarding your interface design:

```
void AddControl(Control& control) {
    mControls.emplace_back(&control)
}
```

You've got a problem here, because

- `Control` is Polymorphic (or at least seems to be based on what code you provided) which means you have to pass by reference or by pointer to get a "complete" object, but
- You don't want to expose an interface where the user has to maintain raw pointers, even briefly, before passing them along to your application.

This is how I would design around this problem:

```
class Window {
public:
    void AddControl(std::unique_ptr<Control> control) {//Note we're passing by value!
        mControls.emplace_back(std::move(control));
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Control>> mControls;
};
```

Then, in your application:

```
class MyFinanceApp : public Application {
public:
    MyFinanceApp() : mMainWindow(make_unique<Window>()) {
        mMainWindow->AddControl(std::make_unique<Button>("testButton"));
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Window> mMainWindow;
};
```

Note that this doesn't necessarily stop your users from doing something stupid, like

```
std::unique_ptr<Window> window_ptr = std::make_Unique<Window>();
Button * button = new Button("This won't be properly deleted!");
window_ptr->AddControl(std::unique_ptr<Button>{button});
delete button; //Whoops!
```

... But there wasn't necessarily anything stopping them from doing that in the first place.

An alternative is to have a "Factory" associated with the Controls. We'd first need to make a modification to `AddControl`:

```
Control & AddControl(std::unique_ptr<Control> control) {
    mControls.emplace_back(std::move(control));
    return *mControls.back();
}

struct ControlFactory {
    static Button & create_button(Window & window, std::string button_text) {
        std::unique_ptr<Button> button_ptr = std::make_unique<Button>(button_text);
        Button & ref = *button_ptr;
        window.AddControl(std::move(button_ptr));
        //ref will NOT be invalidated, because the object will still exist in memory,
        //in the same location in memory as before. Only the unique_ptr will have changed.
        return ref;
    }
};
```

And then you'd simply need to change the access modifiers on all your `Control` subclasses to not allow direct access to their constructors by end-user programmers. Something like this would probably suffice:

```
class Button : public Control {
    /*...*/
protected:
    Button() {/*...*/}
    Button(std::string text) {/*...*/}
    friend class ControlFactory; //Allows ControlFactory to access, even though access is protected.
};
```

Then your users would be storing references on their end, which is safer than pointers, though it does mean you need to guarantee that those references never outlive the application itself.